# How to combine two dataframes vertically and draw a line between the two

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-styles

So I am combining two dataframes. They look something like this:

Dataframe A:

```
index number name
0     2      Joe
1     9      Brian
2     15     Dave
```

Dataframe B:

```
index number name
0     3      Larry
1     25     Tim
```

What I want to do is to have a Dataframe C that looks like this:

```
number name
2      Joe
9      Brian
15     Dave
------------
3      Larry
25     Tim
```

I know I can do `C = A.append(B, ignore_index = True)` and `C = C.style.hide_index()` to hide the indices, but how do I add the line in the middle?

Edit: The line refers to a thickened border between numbers 15 and 3.

Comment: You mention styler hide_index. Are you using Jupyter notebook to render this out or are you exporting to another format like html, latex, excel, _etc._? Additionally, it is unclear if you are specifically looking for a Styler solution _i.e._ not modifying the actual DataFrame data and only change the output appearance. Or if you want to actually add data to the DataFrame in the form of a new row containing dashes.

Comment: Not sure whether the expected output is a new dataframe with a row filled with `-`, or just new way of printing concatenated dataframe.

Comment: I'm doing this on Jupyter Notebook. And yes, I'm probably looking for a Styler solution.